# How to call a php function with a hyperlink "Post" style

Tags: php, html, post, get

I am currently trying to make a hyperlink that calls the same page that I am on, but a different PHP function. This seems like a simple enough solution however I don't want any information displayed in the URL. A "post" seems to be the best solution but I cannot find any results as to how to make this work.

```
<?php 
function myFirst(){ 
    echo 'The First ran successfully.'; 
}
function mySecond(){ 
    echo 'The Second ran successfully.'; 
}
?> 

<html><body> 

<?php 

if (isset($_GET['run'])){
    $linkchoice=$_GET['run'];
}else{
    $linkchoice='';
}

switch($linkchoice){ 
    case 'first' : 
        myFirst(); 
        break; 

    case 'second' : 
        mySecond(); 
        break; 

    default : 
        echo 'no run'; 
} 

?> 

<hr> 
<a href="?run=first">Link to First</a> 
<br/> 
<a href="?run=second">Link to Second</a> 
<br/> 
<a href="?run=0">Refresh No run</a> 

</body></html>
```

Comment: What's the problem? What happens?

Comment: the above code works fine. however; it displays the function "?run=first" in the URL. i want a way so that this doesnt happen

Comment: button is not an option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If u want to use POST by pressing something in the page, u can either use JS to turn that into a POST request, or simply submit a form.

Assuming u use jQuery

```
<a href="baba/was/here/this/is/the/url" onclick="manda_mi()">go somewhere</a>
<form id="koko" style="display:none" target="baba/was/here/this/is/the/url" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="run" value="boo" />
</form>
...
...
function manda_mi(){
  $('#koko').submit();
}
```

Comment: It seems from the question he want syncronus...He can submit a hidden form with JS, no need for AJAX.

Comment: can i get an example of a js function to perform the above code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid Javascript you could wrap the links in a form, and style the buttons to look like normal links.

Basically:

```
<button type="submit" value="first" name="action">Link to First</button> 
<br/> 
<button type="submit" value="second" name="action">Link to Second</button> 
<br/> 
<button type="submit" value="0" name="run">Refresh no Run</button>
```

And then just check what button was pressed.

Although the simplest option is probably Javascript.

Comment: buttons are not an option.